# REST Endpoint with RabbitMQ Producer

Tags: java, rabbitmq

let's say I have a REST endpoint that does this:

1. Receives a json body, do some mapping and then send the message via a messaging producer. (RabbitMQ)

   2. The producer is async.
   3. I have a consumer for the producer in 2 that will do some business logic and post a reply.

Now, I need to receive a reply after some interactions in my rest endpoint.

As the client of my rest call is expecting a reply, the solution that comes to mind is to have the endpoint listening on reply queue with a short timeout, so that I can return the response via REST.

Am I thinking the right way or should I just have a blocking producer and use RPC like it is stated here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html

I want to find the most optimal solution.

Note: I'm not using Spring as I'm learning all these concepts to have a clear understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Producing on queue from an HTTP call on server is fine.

Waiting for a queue and and replying for HTTP call on its response is not preferred way.

1. A reply queue may have many messages on it. What happens if your consume a message meant for different client call? Do you pass the message to appropriate consumer? How do you find out appropriate consumer? You may re-enqueue the message which is wastage of cycles. A message may stay on queue forever.
2. If request queue is flooded and you may have to poll many times to get your result. If you receive reply before client polls you would need to store reply so that you can pass it to client on next call.

These are just scratching the surface of the problems that may arise. If your client is really an HTTP client, you can use above to cover important bases of your application.

A better solution would be to write a consumer on reply queue which would call some endpoint on consumer. However it would still require you to consider cases like failures and retries both on server and client side.

I didn't answer your question but gave you some points to think about. Please don't mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old but if someone is still looking for this. This is mostly related to RPC in rabbitmq. One way could be to set Correlation ID on each produced message (on consumer you receive this Correlation ID and you can match it back), then check if that's the one you are expecting. You set it to unique value (UUID for example) on each request and compare to see if that's the response you are expecting back.

There is also a feature called Direct Reply-to explained nicely: https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html

The producer consume from "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to" and produce with ReplyTo property set to "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to", while the consumer once received and processed message reply to the messages "ReplyTo" property as routing key and empty exchange.

Hope so this helps someone in future.